# Calculate duration between login and logout time when some records are incomplete

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, intervals, date-difference

I want to calculate the total time a user spent on a website. There are 3 scenarios.

1. Records of user's login time and logout time exist.

   -->The total time should be the total of time differences between login and logout.
2. There are records of user's login time, but there is no logout time.

   -->The total time should be marked as -1.
3. The user logins multiple times and there is only one logout time.

   -->The total time should be the total of time differences between the earliest login time and logout time.

**My table**

```
CREATE TABLE #my_table
(
    id BIGINT                      IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
    ,userID                        INT
    ,login_time                    DATETIME
    ,logout_time                   DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO #my_table
          SELECT 222222, '2016-05-19 01:06:00.000', '2016-05-19 01:10:00.000'
UNION ALL SELECT 222222, '2016-05-19 01:12:00.000', '2016-05-19 01:20:00.000'
UNION ALL SELECT 333333, '2016-05-24 14:44:00.000', '2016-05-24 14:47:00.000'
UNION ALL SELECT 333333, '2016-05-24 14:59:00.000', NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 444444, '2016-05-24 14:48:00.000', '2016-05-24 14:49:00.000'
UNION ALL SELECT 444444, '2016-05-24 14:50:00.000', NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 444444, '2016-05-24 14:51:00.000', NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 444444, '2016-05-24 14:53:00.000', '2016-05-24 14:59:00.000'
```

**Intended result**

[image]

For most of the cases, the records captured in database will be case 1, but sometimes case 2 and case 3 will also be captured. I need one script to  calculate the total login time for all cases.

How should I query it?

Comment: Please add a tag with the version of  SQL Server and show your sample data as a **text**, not image. It would be even better if your sample data was in the form of `INSERT` statement.

Comment: Please provide the sample data as **text**

Comment: @VladimirBaranov: Thanks! I have added in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query below uses `ROW_NUMBER` function several times to pick the needed rows and `LEAD` function to "look ahead" when `logout_time` is NULL. `LEAD` is available since SQL Server 2012.

Run the query step-by-step, CTE-by-CTE and examine intermediate results to understand how it works.

`CTE_Groups` is a classic `gaps-and-islands` query to mark the rows with consecutive NULLs in `logout_time`.

`CTE_RN` assigns numbers to rows in such a way, that consecutive NULLs in `logout_time` get consecutive numbers. This result is filtered in `CTE_Fixed` to get only first row per group of NULLs. If `logout_time` is NULL, then `LEAD` function is used to pick a value from the next row to make the `fixed_logout_time`.

The row with NULL `logout_time` and next row with non-NULL `logout_time` would be listed together in `CTE_Fixed`. We need to pick only one row out of such pairs. Same method - use `ROW_NUMBER` in `CTE_FixedRN` and pick the first row in `CTE_Sum`.

Then we can calculate the `Duration` in minutes and group the sum by `userID`.

If there is no non-NULL `logout_time`, the `DATEDIFF` would return NULL, which will be replaced with some large negative number. In the final `SELECT` the negative `Duration` would be replaced with `-1` to indicate that last interval is still open.

```
WITH
CTE_Groups
AS
(
    SELECT
        userID
        ,login_time
        ,logout_time
        ,ROW_NUMBER() 
            OVER(PARTITION BY userID ORDER BY login_time)
        - ROW_NUMBER() 
            OVER(PARTITION BY userID, logout_time ORDER BY login_time) AS GroupNumber
    FROM #my_table
)
,CTE_RN
AS
(
    SELECT
        userID
        ,login_time
        ,logout_time
        ,ROW_NUMBER()
            OVER(PARTITION BY userID, GroupNumber ORDER BY login_time) AS rn
    FROM CTE_Groups
)
,CTE_Fixed
AS
(
    SELECT
        userID
        ,login_time
        ,ISNULL(logout_time, LEAD(logout_time) 
            OVER(PARTITION BY userID ORDER BY login_time)) AS fixed_logout_time
    FROM CTE_RN
    WHERE rn = 1
)
,CTE_FixedRN
AS
(
    SELECT
        userID
        ,login_time
        ,fixed_logout_time
        ,ROW_NUMBER() 
            OVER(PARTITION BY userID, fixed_logout_time ORDER BY login_time) AS rn
    FROM CTE_Fixed
)
,CTE_Sum
AS
(
    SELECT
        userID
        ,SUM(ISNULL(
            DATEDIFF(minute, login_time, fixed_logout_time),
            -1000000)) AS Duration
    FROM CTE_FixedRN
    WHERE rn = 1
    GROUP BY userID
)
SELECT
    userID
    ,CASE WHEN Duration < 0 THEN -1 ELSE Duration END AS Duration
FROM CTE_Sum
ORDER BY userID;
```

**Result**

```
+--------+----------+
| userID | Duration |
+--------+----------+
| 222222 |       12 |
| 333333 |       -1 |
| 444444 |       10 |
+--------+----------+
```

Comment: This solution is briliant.. thanks so much,Vladimir!

Comment: @eric, you are welcome. Consider upvoting useful answers and accepting the answer that helped you most.

Answer (score 1):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#my_table') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #my_table

CREATE TABLE #my_table
(
    id BIGINT                      IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
    ,userID                        INT
    ,login_time                    DATETIME
    ,logout_time                   DATETIME
);

DECLARE @MT TABLE
(
     id                            BIGINT
    ,userID                        INT
    ,login_time                    DATETIME
    ,logout_time                   DATETIME
);


DECLARE @DRes TABLE (
    userID          INT,
    logtime         INT
    )

DECLARE @Counter1 INT = 0,
    @login_time1        DATETIME,
    @logout_time1       DATETIME,
    @login_time2        DATETIME

INSERT INTO #my_table VALUES
     (222222, '2016-05-19 01:06:00.000', '2016-05-19 01:10:00.000')
    ,(222222, '2016-05-19 01:12:00.000', '2016-05-19 01:20:00.000')
    ,(333333, '2016-05-24 14:44:00.000', '2016-05-24 14:47:00.000')
    ,(333333, '2016-05-24 14:59:00.000', NULL)
    ,(444444, '2016-05-24 14:48:00.000', '2016-05-24 14:49:00.000')
    ,(444444, '2016-05-24 14:50:00.000', NULL)
    ,(444444, '2016-05-24 14:51:00.000', NULL)
    ,(444444, '2016-05-24 14:53:00.000', '2016-05-24 14:59:00.000')

INSERT INTO @MT
    SELECT * FROM #my_table

;WITH MaxLog 
    AS (
    SELECT userID, MAX(login_time) AS max_login
        FROM @MT
        GROUP BY userID
    ),

DelRec
    AS (
    SELECT ml.userID
        FROM MaxLog ml
        LEFT JOIN @MT mt
            ON ml.userID = mt.userID
        WHERE mt.logout_time IS NULL
            AND ml.max_login = mt.login_time
    )

DELETE mt
    FROM @MT mt
    INNER JOIN
        DelRec dr
        ON mt.userID = dr.userID
    WHERE mt.logout_time IS NOT NULL

;WITH StillIn
    AS (
    SELECT userID, COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM @MT
        GROUP BY userID
            HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
    )

UPDATE mt
    SET logout_time = DATEADD(mi,-1,login_time)
        FROM @MT mt
        JOIN StillIn si
            ON si.UserID = mt.UserId

WHILE @Counter1 < (SELECT MAX(id) FROM @MT)
    BEGIN
    SET @Counter1 += 1
    SET @login_time1 = (SELECT login_time FROM @MT WHERE id = @Counter1)
    SET @logout_time1 = (SELECT logout_time FROM @MT WHERE id = @Counter1)
    IF @logout_time1 IS NULL
        BEGIN
        IF @login_time2 IS NULL
            BEGIN
            SET @login_time2 = @login_time1
            END
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
        IF @login_time2 IS NULL
            BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @DRes
                SELECT userID, DATEDIFF(mi,@login_time1,@logout_time1)
                FROM @MT
                    WHERE id = @Counter1
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @DRes
                SELECT userID, DATEDIFF(mi,@login_time2,@logout_time1)
                FROM @MT
                    WHERE id = @Counter1
            SET @login_time2 = NULL
            END
        END
    END

SELECT userID, SUM(logtime)
    FROM @DRes
    GROUP BY userID
```

Comment: Ran out of time. I'll come back and finish this if I can. But if not at least somebody has a better starting point.

Comment: So, this is pretty ugly, I'll admit that. But it works.

Comment: To me the biggest problem with your approach is not the `WHILE` loop and building result row-by-row (which is likely to be slow), but the fact that you change the original data.

Comment: Right, I thought about that later. I'll go ahead and fix it. I'm also going to modify the original insert statement...hopefully that works with your system?